# How can i Build Dressing room app by Augmented Reality

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, wikitude, android-augmented-reality

I Wanted To Develop A Augmented Reality Android Application.That can Be like a Dressing Room App.Anyone can Try for Any dresses Stored in our E-commerce Site The can take an order for Purchased any dresses.

I need some help ..What technique i can use. Which SDK can be better for such type AR application .Which tools can be used(Android Studio or Unity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Unity very easily. you'll need to download the package 'Vuforia' for using AR with Unity. Read up on Vuforia's documentation pages. For android applications, you can download Android's SDK for AR, and for apple use the Apple ARKit.

Comment: But in vuforia there is no body tracking or face tracking system... what can be the procedure

Comment: That is true. Body tracking is not possible on Unity games, and I'd suggest using ARKit for that